# How can I protect my php application by licence key?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am developing a chat application in php and i want to sell this over internet. How I can I make it licence protected, that only those person who have bought licence key are able to use it. There will be a different licence for different domain.
What how can I achieve this?

Comment: As for PHP code you can protect it with http://www.ioncube.com/ or http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/

Comment: did you fiind the solution if yes please share

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're going to struggle with the three banes of licensing:

1. Someone smart will just take the code out
2. You'll need to license per server or to have the keys circulating on the internet
3. Most people will just get a free alternative

To remedy the first one...you can't. PHP is not compiled. the other two are less about code.

Comment: I am still confused about this that how can I achieve this. Firstly I will allow them to add their domain name before they can download and then provide them licence key. But I am going to give them the code then can modify it and distribute it again. Or either I have to put some part of code on my server?

Comment: The first part will only guarantee that downloads are done. It won't provide immunity to someone hosting it elsewhere - or torrenting it. invision board 1.3 comes to mind on this very issue. As for redistribution, this bans you from putting any license checks in the code, as the redistribution target will not be able to get this. So, effectively, your best (and only) bet is to just trust people not to re-upload elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Usually on the internet what you can see is not licenses but memberships, unless you mean to install your application on internal servers of other companies, if that is the case, there are many installers setups that help you restrict an installation by provising an encripted key, in that case would be your license.

Comment: Can you please provide me details about these installer setups.

Comment: you will probably have to use a third-party, this might be an example of that kind of software: http://www.desaware.com/products/licensingsystem/index.aspx

Comment: Thanks for link, but I think this will not work with php app.